# ipdb debugger, step out of cycle

Tags: python, debugging, ipdb

Is there a command to step out of cycles (say, for or while) while debugging on ipdb without having to use breakpoints out of them?

I use the `until` command to step out of list comprehensions, but don't know how could I do a similar thing, if possible, of entire loop blocks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This could sound obvious: **jump makes you jump**. 
This means that you don't execute the lines you jump: you should use this to skip code that you don’t want to run.

You probably need **tbreak** (Temporary breakpoint, which is removed automatically when it is first hit. The arguments are the same as break) as I did when I found this page.

Answer (score 30):

I believe this is the intent of the `until` command.  It's like a `next` except that when a jump occurs to a previous line number for the loop, it will continue until exiting the loop.

```
unt(il)
Continue execution until the line with a number greater than the current
one is reached or until the current frame returns
```

In general, to "step out" of the current function, use `return`.

```
r(eturn)
Continue execution until the current function returns.
```

Comment: nope, until steps out of list comprehensions for example. It continues execution UNTIL reching a different line number as the current one, just that. If inside some code block (for, while, anything else), there's no way but with breakpoints, as far as I have researched

Comment: @Javier Navoa What you described for `until` is the behavior of `next`. I believe he is right: `until` is just like `next` except that it always goes down. In that way `until` can effectively be used to go out of loops, but it can take several times (the number of lines remaining in the loop).

Comment: The trap is that the debugger understands list comprehensions as several lines, but it is the same for `next` and `until`.

Answer (score 24):

You can use `j <line number> (jump)` to go to another line.
for example, `j 28` to go to line 28.

Comment: as pointed out by jimifiti, `jump` skips the jumped lines, so it is not similar to `until`

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use another debugger, [trepan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan/0.4.9), has more ways you can step. It is more gdb-like. So you can give a count of how many times you want to step. Or you can give a line number in a [continue](http://python2-trepan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands/running/continue.html) debugger command which in essence sets a temporary breakpoint at the line and then issues "continue". Other things that change stepping are ["set different"](http://python2-trepan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands/set/different.html). See also the even suffixes you can put on [step](http://python2-trepan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands/running/step.html).

Note that like ipdb, there is syntax highlighting of the source text.